# Does adding server side code in markup page (aspx) affect performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

At my previous job, our team architect was strongly against including any server side code in the markup, even simple ID's, so this code would not be allowed to get checked in:

```
<script>
    var el = document.getElementByID('<% SomeElement.ClientID %>')
</script>
```

instead you had to inject it into javascript via Page.ClientScript.Register...

His reason was that asp.net has to recompile a page every time if it has those server code includes.

That didn't sound right for me but I couldn't find any proof of either.

Any ideas? Does that change performance or not? I know that server side code in markup is not good because of difficulties in debugging and readability and the whole idea of separatin gcode form markup, but I am only interested in performance differences.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you left out the actual code example.

Comment: but, adding ID attributes to your elements can be useful for client-side code.

Comment: You can run Chrome Developer tools with Network panel selected and watch the time it takes to load. That is a good way to test, and I expect it to take a matter of milliseconds longer if anything.

Comment: That site we've been working on is very high load - hundreds of thousands or simultaneous connections to the farm, so even milliseconds did matter. But I see from the answers that there shouldn't be any difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your architect is wrong.

ASP.NET compiles a page once, regardless of whether or not it contains any C# code. It will recompile the page only if it detects that the ASPX file was changed since last compilation.

Comment: Do you have a source? Or did you observe this on your own?

Comment: That's what I kept telling him for two years I worked with him, but he demanded proof that I couldn't figure out how to get. I still want to get back to him with this, any idea how I could prove it?

Comment: Yeah I think all those files get stuffed in `\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files` if you want to look..

Comment: Second link that came up in Google search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx. Quote: "*After pages and code files have been compiled the first time, the compiled resources are cached, so that subsequent requests to the same page are extremely efficient*"

Comment: @sq33G no link to proof, however, you can view the cached compiled files in your Temporary ASP.Net folder.

Comment: http://www.codersource.net/asp-net/asp-net-articles/internals-of-asp-net-compilation-and-execution.aspx read the "Compilation of Script Inside the aspx pages" part!

Answer (score 0):

Use a profiling tool (like dotTrace from JetBrains) to definitively tell you the performance metrics.  Write 2 pages...one with and one without server-side stuff...and test.